# Sublime Text 2 slow -- disable plugins for large files?

Tags: plugins, autocomplete, sublimetext2

Sublime Text 2 is running very slowly for me on large text files (1000s of lines of code), and I suspect it is due to the plugins I have installed (like SublimeCodeIntel), particularly the auto-complete. How do I temporarily disable plugins in Sublime Text 2, or even better, automatically disable them only on large files?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found it -- if you hit Command-Shift-P (on a Mac), there is a ``Package Control: Disable Package'' option (and a corresponding option for enabling packages again).

Answer (score 31):

You can also append the following to the settings file if you want to disable the popups whenever a plugin makes sublime slow down (although I'm aware that's not exactly what you're looking for, it may be useful for future Googlers):

```
"detect_slow_plugins": false
```

Comment: More information for this answer: Add the above line mentioned by Matt to *Preferences.sublime-settings — User* file. You can access this file from the top menu: *Preferences » Settings — User*.