# Sublime Text: disable all packages

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3083.

When I load a file with several thousand lines and try to edit it, it gets amazingly un-responsive to the point that adding/removing even one character takes it seconds.

I have > 20 packages installed and I need a way to disable all of them at once, to check if this issue is package related or o not.

I've searched around and I know that you can disable packages [one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546123/sublime-text-2-slow-disable-plugins-for-large-files) but that's not good when lots of packages are installed. According to [this post](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=7083) in the sublime forum, there is no way to do this but the post is rather old (and also not an official statement)

So, is there a way to do this? Perhaps with a package or a `--no-packages` flag or some other trick?

---

**BTW**: for the sake of completeness, after applying the solution I found that there were two packages responsible for the lag: [GitGutter](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter) and [WordHighlight](https://github.com/SublimeText/WordHighlight).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the laggy packages!

Comment: Also lead here by sublime text lagging substantially, even on small files. Disabled GitGutter, and voila...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The best thing I can think of is to keep a list of the package names that you can copy and paste into your preferences file in the "ignored packages" section. If you have any sort of linter or code intel that might be the culprit if it's several thousand lines.

```
"ignored_packages":
[
    "SublimeCodeIntel",
    "Vintage"
]
```

Another thing to try would be to just make a copy of your `Packages/Users/Package Control.sublime-settings` file, then edit the original and delete all the listed packages there and restart ST3. Definitely make that copy first in case it screws up.

---

Gabriel reports he ultimately solved the issue by copying the list of installed packages out of the `Packages/Users/Package Control.sublime-settings` file and paste them into the `ignored_packages` section of his preferences file.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I copied the list of installed packages from `Packages/Users/Package Control.sublime-settings` and pasted into the `"ignored_packages"` section of `Packages/Users/Preferences.sublime-settings`. Indeed this is an issue with a package. Now to find the culprit. Thanks again!

Comment: That's cool. I was tryin to add "*" as a package to ignore and I get this nice error: `It appears a package is trying to ignore itself, causing a loop` hahaha

Comment: Yeah they really ought to make it an option, good question. Also editing to highlight the final solution.

Comment: Windows users will find  the file at `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` or equivalent.

Comment: And an official note on the said solution: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#disabling-packages

Answer (score 5):

**Packages can be simply disabled as follows**

1. Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open *Command Palette*
2. Type **disable**, select *Package Control: Disable Package*
3. This will give the list of all the Installed Packages, click on the one which you want to disable.

That's it. And you can enable disabled package anytime, just type enable in step:2.

Comment: No one talked about removing a package. The question is about disabling all packages at once: "*I've searched around and I know that you can disable packages one by one but that's not good when lots of packages are installed.*"