# Wrap selection in html tag suddenly stopped working in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Help! One of my favourite and most-used keyboard shortcuts has suddenly stopped working in ST3:

**Shift + Alt + W**
*(Wrap selection in HTML tag)*

I've recently updated to the latest version which is currently 3114. I've checked the keymap settings, and nothing that I can see there is overriding it. I've also tried disabling all installed packages, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856557/sublime-disable-all-packages). Still nothing happening. That shortcut has just completely dropped dead. Any ideas? I *need* it back!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From Sublime Text, go to the `Tools` menu -> `Browse Packages`.
2. Create a folder called `XML`.
3. Create a folder called `Snippets`.
4. Create a file called `long-tag.sublime-snippet`.
5. Open it.
6. Paste in the following (from https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/master/XML/Snippets/long-tag.sublime-snippet):

   ```
   <snippet>
     <content><![CDATA[<${1:p}>${2:$SELECTION}</${1/([^ ]+).*/$1/}>]]></content>
     <tabTrigger>&lt;</tabTrigger>
     <scope>text.xml</scope>
     <description>Long Tag</description>
   </snippet>
   ```
7. Save it
8. Copy it up one level, to the `XML` folder.

The keybinding will now work.

Comment: Wow... you, sir, are a hero. I can't say I actually understand what's going on here... but it works

Comment: thanks again for your answer. I've subsequently discovered another annoying problem: when autocompleting a tag pair with `tab`, I used to be able to then hit `return` to insert a new blank line between the two tags, and have the cursor sitting waiting on it at the correct indentation. Now it just inserts a line break, as per a standard text-editor. For goodness sake, I don't understand what has happened to ST and I will think twice about accepting the next update. I should perhaps open a new question about this, but it might be tangentially related to this one?

Comment: I think it would be best to open a new question - the way the XML and HTML tag identation works has changed recently and is no longer snippet based, so will have a different solution