# Copy and Pasting Rows / Cells from Google Sheets to Sublime Text

Tags: google-sheets, sublimetext3, sublimetext

When I am trying to copy / paste cells / rows from Google Sheets to Sublime Text, they get copied in a single line. How can I make so that each row / cell is copied in a new line in Sublime Text? Before, that was the behaviour, but now it changed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you've described. Latest ST, stable channel. MacOS, Linux, Windows. Firefox, Edge, Mullvad. So it seems it is your setup. We'd need more info to narrow down where the problem lies. Try a different browser, try [disabling ST packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30857054/279798), etc.

Comment: Hi @JoelReid thanks for taking a look into this. I have already tested other browsers, same behaviour. Could it be related with hardware? I think this problem arised when I switched to a MacBook M2 with Apple chip.

Comment: He's correct, this is a new(er) problem. Would love a solution to paste as lines.
Via MacOS and Google sheets.